# GLKViewControl, Storyboard and tap events

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, glkview

I have a problem with a `GLKViewController` (subclass) used in a `Storyboard`: it refuses to handle tap events.

I added a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the `GLKViewController` (subclass) in the Storyboard and linked it to a 'tapDetected' method:

[image]

```
- (IBAction) tapDetected:(id)sender {
      NSLog(@"tap\n");
      [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: ![self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden]];
} // tapDetected
```

This exactly how I manage - successfully - the taps in other view controllers in the same `Storyboard`. Only the `GLKViewController` does not receive the event: neither the log nor the navigation bar are affected by the tap.

I searched for any specific need of GLKViewControllers but could not find any. Do you have any idea and/or suggestion?

---

It looks like if I add a `touchesBegan` method everything works ok. So the question is: what's the point of the gesture recognizer in the Storyboard?

Comment: So it looks like the class must have a touchesBegan … method: the tap gesture recognizer is simply ignored.

Comment: It'll work in code - I have a GLKView which uses gesture recognisers instantiated in code.

Comment: So basically we cannot use the graphical interface editor with GLKView and tap events?